# Is wso2 is 5.0 SP1 case sensitive?

Tags: wso2, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

We are using WSO2 Is 5.0 SP1. We have configured ReadOnly LDAP and also using entitlement feature of the identity server. The XACML policy which we have defined on WSO2 IS derives its entitlement from the roles assigned to the user. Our observation is that WSO2 IS does an actual match of the username i.e its case sensitive.If we pass the username in the same case as that is available in WSO2 user list it returns proper entitlement. Is there any fix for the same in WSO2 Is 5.0 SP1? Any workaround would also help.

```
<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" PolicyId="AdministratorPolicy" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:rule-combining-algorithm:permit-overrides" Version="1.0">
<Target></Target>
<Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="Rule1">
  <Condition>
     <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:and">
        <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-at-least-one-member-of">
           <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
              <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Test</AttributeValue>
          </Apply>
           <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
        </Apply>
        <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-is-in">
           <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Internal/Administrator</AttributeValue>
           <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/claims/role" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
        </Apply>
     </Apply>
  </Condition>
</Rule>
Rule Effect="Deny" RuleId="Rule2"></Rule>
 </Policy>
```

Thanks in advance,
Cijoy

Comment: Can you please post the xacml policy you used?

Comment: So the issue happens when the XACML engine try to retrieve the roles of the user right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this behavior happens because of the way you wrote the xacml policy.

Have you use `urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal` to match username in your xaml policy?

if so, try `urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:function:string-equal-ignore-case` instead of above. It should solve the issue.

---

**EDIT :** With the updated question XACML policy, the issue sees to be XACML engine does not retrieve roles when it does not get username from the subjectin correct case.

That means, default PIP does not return roles if the username not in correct case.

Thinking of this angle, to answer your original question

**Is wso2 is 5.0 SP1 case sensitive?**

For usernames\role-names case sensitivity if the Identity Server inherits from the underlying user store it plugged in to. If you connect IS to a Active Directory, usually usernames\rolenames aren't case sensitive. If you deploy IS over a Oracle user store, usually usernames\rolenames are handled in case sensitive manner.

---

**Solution**

But more specifically for your scenario, if you wanted to retrieve (Internal) role list regardless of the case of the username. There is a reported [issue](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-2053) regarding this behaviour and Identity Server 5.0.0 does include those fixes. So you can try following,

1. Open `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/user-mgt.xml` file.
2. Add `GetRoleListOfInternalUserSQL` property with mentioned value under the `<UserManager>/<Realm>/<Configuration>` tag as follows,

   ```
   <UserManager>
      <Realm>
         <Configuration>
           ...
           <Property name="GetRoleListOfInternalUserSQL">
               SELECT UM_ROLE_NAME FROM UM_HYBRID_USER_ROLE, UM_HYBRID_ROLE WHERE UPPER(UM_USER_NAME)=UPPER ( ? ) AND UM_HYBRID_USER_ROLE.UM_ROLE_ID=UM_HYBRID_ROLE.UM_ID AND UM_HYBRID_USER_ROLE.UM_TENANT_ID=? AND UM_HYBRID_ROLE.UM_TENANT_ID=? AND UM_HYBRID_USER_ROLE.UM_DOMAIN_ID=(SELECT UM_DOMAIN_ID FROM UM_DOMAIN WHERE UM_TENANT_ID=? AND UM_DOMAIN_NAME=?)
           </Property>
         </Configuration>
        ...
      </Realm>
   <UserManager>
   ```
3. Restart the server

Now your policy should evaluate as expected for any case of the username

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Our policy checks for the roles against a list of resources and does not compare the username directly. Hence when  we invoke from TryIt tool as well with case mismatched subject-name and resource it fails.

Comment: I have updated the answer, from the facts i got from XACML policy.

Comment: Thanks a lot DarRay. This worked for us. Now the entitlements as well as Claim management works as expected.

Comment: You are welcome..! It's nice to hear you got it working.